# Mystery java.lang.RuntimeException: at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked (PowerManager.java:2212)

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, runtimeexception, powermanager

App has been running in production for many years suddenly decided to throw a onetime RuntimeException.

This was reported by the Play Console crash tracking page.  About all I know about it is that it happend on a Galaxy S7 running Android 8.0

The complete stack trace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3399)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1780)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked (PowerManager.java:2212)
  at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire (PowerManager.java:2193)
  at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:111)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzav.zzd (Unknown Source:56)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzav.zzb (Unknown Source:33)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver.zza (Unknown Source:39)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver.zza (Unknown Source:30)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source:10)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3392)
```

There most likely was a nice descriptive message included in the thrown exception, but unfortunately the exception message is not and never has been included in Play Console Crash reports.

If I knew how to find the source code for this particular version of the PowerManager class, I could look it up there.  But alas, that has also proven to be beyond my capabilities.

Any help or suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks